# Limit Results to Previous 7 days Monday to Sunday each week

Tags: sql, teradatasql

I wan to limit my results everytime to  to the previous 7 days, but this query always throws an error and does not seem to be working as intended:

```
   SELECT 


   DD.DATE_DATE AS Rcv_Date,

    elig.PL_PREMIUMDESC,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(sERV.claim_nbr))  as Claim_Nbr


        from
        ft_service SERV

        inner join ft_claim claim 
        on SERV.claim_nbr=claim.claim_nbr 


         inner join  medical_cost_category mcc
         on SERV.medical_cost_category_dim_ck=mcc.medical_cost_category_dim_ck
    
         INNER JOIN DIM_DATE DD 
         ON DD.DATE_DIM_CK = CLAIM.RCVD_DATE_DIM_CK 
    

    
               left join member_elig_curr elig 
         on SERV.member_elig_curr_ck=elig.member_elig_curr_ck
    
          WHERE DD.DATE_DATE - ((DD.DATE_DATE -  CURRENT_DATE) MOD 7) ---GET ME PREVIOUS 7 DATS FOR 
         RCV DATE 
    
    

           AND elig.PL_CODE IN ('XXX', 'XXXA', 'XXXB') 
             AND SERV.CLAIM_NBR NOT LIKE '%XD%'
    
         GROUP BY 1, 2
```

Comment: Did you write all that code without even trying to execute during the process? Take smaller steps, write a simple SELECT, execute it, add a little more, execute etc,

Comment: I have done all that it work, the only part that does not work is: "DD.DATE_DATE - ((DD.DATE_DATE -  CURRENT_DATE) MOD 7) ---GET ME PREVIOUS 7 DATS FOR " to limit the result to the previous 7 days, dont know what else is missing there

Comment: Just a tip, make it easy to assist you - show us the smallest possible query needed to reproduce your problem. [mcve].

Comment: SELECT 


DD.DATE_DATE AS Claim_Rcv_Date


from  claim claim 


  


  INNER JOIN DIM_DATE DD 
   ON DD.DATE_DIM_CK = CLAIM.CLAIM_RCVD_DATE_DIM_CK 
  


        
        WHERE (DD.DATE_DATE - ((DD.DATE_DATE -  CURRENT_DATE) MOD 7)

Comment: That right there is the smallest version of the code to produce the problem!

Comment: But there's no comparison in the WHERE clause, just a calculation.

Comment: Oh, I got some guidance here on how to formulate the last 7 days https://downloads.teradata.com/forum/general/reg-how-to-extract-a-week-number-from-date-column

Comment: Execute `SELECT DD.DATE_DATE, DD.DATE_DATE - ((DD.DATE_DATE -  CURRENT_DATE) MOD 7) FROM DIM_DATE DD`, and you will probably see what's needed.

Comment: What do you mean? I mean that would execute, the issue is how do I include that in the where clause to limit my data to the previous week.

Comment: Don't post multiple copies of the same question, just apply multiple tags. If you think you applied the wrong tags or omitted a tag, edit the original post.

Answer (score 0):

```
DD.DATE_DATE BETWEEN  (current_date - INTERVAL '7' DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE
```

That is the answer to the question. Setting that in the where clause will always limit the data to the last 7 days.